# How can I sync photo folders in my laptop with my 4s iphone?

Tags: laptop, itunes, sync, iphone, photos

I have about 50 folders on my laptop with various pictures in them e.g. 2006 Germany World Cup.  Upto the 4S I was able to manually copy the folders back and forth using Windows explorer, but this isn't possible any more since the folder structure no longer appears on the iPhone.  If I try to synch them using itunes I just get a Photo library blob of 6,000 pics containing the contents of all my folders.

The only way to have my folder structure that I see is to manually create the 50 folders on my iPhone and copy the pics from the Photo library.  This is obviously incredibly time consuming, not to mention asinine.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When syncing, be sure that you are syncing a folder that contains all of the other folders of photos.

Once you are sure that this is configured correctly, resync your iPhone. It should have no reason not to place each photo album in a separate folder on your iPhone.

Hope this helps.